# Filter all files in any depth by file prefix inside a directory

Tags: java, file-io, apache-commons-vfs

I'm using Apache Commons VFS2.0 to access files both in a local file system and a remote file system. I'm trying to find a way to filter all the descendent files in any depth with `FileType=File` and has a given filePrefix with the file name. I was able to do it for the same case except for file prefix, but for file extension, as follows.

```
FileSelector fileSelector = new FileExtensionSelector("extensions...");
directory.findFiles(fileSelector);
```

In this way, I was able to fetch all the files(no folders) in any depth with the given extension. I have tried the below approach but it only works for matching files with depth=1.

```
FileFilterSelector prefixFileSelector = new FileFilterSelector(new PrefixFileFilter("Prefix"));
directory.findFiles(prefixFileSelector);
```

Appreciate if anyone can give a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
new FileFilterSelector(fileFilter) {
    @Override
    public boolean traverseDescendents(FileSelectInfo fileInfo) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean includeFile(FileSelectInfo fileInfo) throws Exception {
        return accept(fileInfo);
    }
}
```